# How to connect telegram bot to local http server

Tags: python, api, ssh

I'm trying to connect my telegram bot to local server with this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2CjMIZEpEU
This was the only understandable guide I've found, I got api id and api hash, entered them, downloaded all files(I'm using server on Debian 11), but I do not understand how to connect to server with base_url

Here is a part of my code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater('<token>',
                      base_url = 'http://<my_server_ip>:5500/bot')


    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I'm trying to run the server, which IP address should I use? My hosting IP or should I buy an extra ip address.

If i use my hosting IP, i can not find opened port for it, so it doesn't work
I bought http proxy, checked it on special website and it seems to work, but when I'm trying to run the server, i get this error:

```
PM2      | App [bot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [bot:0] online
0|bot    | /root/main.py:50: TelegramDeprecationWarning: Old Handler API is deprecated - see https://git.io/fxJuV for details
0|bot    |   updater = Updater('<api_token>',
0|bot    | Bot is online
0|bot    | Traceback (most recent call last):
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 183, in _parse
0|bot    |     data = json.loads(decoded_s)
0|bot    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
0|bot    |     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
0|bot    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
0|bot    |     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
0|bot    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
0|bot    |     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
0|bot    | json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
0|bot    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
0|bot    | Traceback (most recent call last):
0|bot    |   File "/root/main.py", line 59, in <module>
0|bot    |     main()
0|bot    |   File "/root/main.py", line 55, in main
0|bot    |     updater.start_polling()
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 258, in start_polling
0|bot    |     self.job_queue.start()
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/ext/jobqueue.py", line 311, in start
0|bot    |     name="Bot:{}:job_queue".format(self._dispatcher.bot.id))
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 54, in decorator
0|bot    |     self.get_me()
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/decorator.py", line 232, in fun
0|bot    |     return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 67, in decorator
0|bot    |     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 251, in get_me
0|bot    |     result = self._request.get(url, timeout=timeout)
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 277, in get
0|bot    |     result = self._request_wrapper('GET', url, **urlopen_kwargs)
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 238, in _request_wrapper
0|bot    |     message = self._parse(resp.data)
0|bot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 185, in _parse
0|bot    |     raise TelegramError('Invalid server response')
0|bot    | telegram.error.TelegramError: Invalid server response
PM2      | App [bot:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | Script /usr/bin/bash had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
```

My question is:
Where i take IP:PORT for base_url, should it be from hosting or somewhere else?